# Не изменяется текст в виджете TextView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. У меня проблемка. 
Есть переменна int sitost = 25; я хочу сделать чтоб при нажатии на button1 в переменную sitost добавляло + 10. 
Делаю это таким образом, но значение не добавляет:

1. Код файла gameview.xml:

   ```
    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/sitost"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="TextView" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:onClick="plus"
   android:text="Button" />
   ```
2. Код файла GameView.java:

   ```
   public class GameView extends Activity {

   TextView SitostCat;
   int sitcoll = 25;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
   /* Скрываем строку состояния */
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   setContentView(R.layout.gameview);



   SitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
   SitostCat.setText("Сытость " + sitcoll);


   }

   public void plus(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
       case R.id.button1:
   sitcoll = sitcoll + 10;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

При нажатии на кнопку не чего не происходит. В чем моя ошибка? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А вы как проверяете значение переменной? Возможно, что после изменения переменной нужно добавить изменение текста (в `TextView` `sitost`)?

Comment: провераю значение как есть, тоесть, строкой SitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
SitostCat.setText("Сытость " + sitcoll); которая выше.или нужно как то по другому?

Comment: изменил чуть код на:         public void plus(View view) {
     switch (view.getId()) {
     case R.id.button1:
      SitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
      SitostCat.setText("Сытость " + sitcoll);
      
sitcoll = sitcoll + 10;
   break;
     }
 } и заработало. правильно ли использовать такой способ?

Comment: в комментарий не влезло, написал ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы как проверяете значение переменной? Возможно, что после изменения переменной нужно добавить изменение текста (в `TextView` `sitost`)?

Обычно для подобных переменных делается свой setter, который устанавливает значение переменной, а также может "автоматом" установить новое значение в `TextView`. Ведь если вам нужно будет менять переменную, например, ещё в пяти местах программы, то придётся везде дублировать подобный код... А если позже захотите поменять `TextView` на, например, изображение, то придётся вносить достаточно много одинаковых исправлений.

У меня нет опыта работы с Java, потому не знаю, есть ли возможность задавать setter и getter для переменной (например, в языке D я могу определить член класса как property и тогда при простой операции присвоения, вроде `x = 5;` или использования, вроде `int n = x;`, будет исполняться заданный код). Но в общих чертах, смысл один:

```
int value = 0;

void valueSet(int val) {
    value = val;
    // здесь же любые нужные вам действия, например
    SitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
    SitostCat.setText("Сытость " + val);
}

int valueGet() {
    return value;
}
```

то есть любое обращение к переменной идёт через эти методы, а не напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что код в методе `onCreate()` выполняется только один раз - при старте активити, соответственно то, что вы там прописали `setText()` тоже будет выполнено только при старте.
Для динамического изменения состояния виджетов нужно использовать методы, реагирующие на текущие события, в вашем случае это клик по кнопке, изменять состояние виджета нужно именно там - когда произошло событие. 
С другой стороны, нет никакой надобности каждый раз получать ссылку на один и тот же объект (виджет)  - это нужно сделать однажды, при создании активити и сохранить значение в поле класса для последующего использования в любых методах активити.
В коде вся эта писанина выглядит следующим образом:

```
 public class GameView extends Activity {

   TextView mSitostCat;
    int mSitcoll = 25;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.game_view);

        mSitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
        mSitostCat.setText("Сытость " + mSitcoll);
  }

  public void plus(View view) {
   switch (view.getId()) {
     case R.id.button1:
       mSitcoll += 10;
       mSitostCat.setText("Сытость " + mSitcoll);
       break;
   }
  }
```

PS: По соглашению оформления кода в Java имена переменных принято писать с маленькой буквы, слова отделять большой буквой. Кроме того, имена полей класса принято начинать с буквы 'm' .
Слова в именах .xml файлов и идентификаторах разделять '_' - привыкайте сразу следовать этим правилам и программисткая жизнь в дальнейшем будет легче. В коде выше я внес исправления, как **должно** выглядеть все это.